# I do not understand this Rails SyntaxError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm just beginning to work through Agile Web Development with Rails, 4th Edition, and I've run into a SyntaxError while setting up my first application in Chapter 6.  The code is below as well as the error.  I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.1.3.  I tried to follow the book exactly, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  I saw a similar error on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565066/dont-understand-this-rails-error-message) but it did not fix my problem.

**Here is the index.html for Product**

```
    <h1>Listing products</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>\</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Image url</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= product.\ %></td>
    <td><%= product.title %></td>
    <td><%= product.description %></td>
    <td><%= product.image_url %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Product', new_product_path %>
```

**And here is the error that I'm getting**

```
SyntaxError in Products#index

Showing C:/Sites/work/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb where line #17 raised:

C:/Sites/work/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb:17: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
...tput_buffer.append= ( product.\ );@output_buffer.safe_concat...
...                               ^
C:/Sites/work/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
'); end 
       ^
C:/Sites/work/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb:33: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
C:/Sites/work/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb:35: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
Extracted source (around line #17):

14: 
15: <% @products.each do |product| %>
16:   <tr>
17:     <td><%= product.\ %></td>
18:     <td><%= product.title %></td>
19:     <td><%= product.description %></td>
20:     <td><%= product.image_url %></td>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/products/index.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/Sites/work/depot
```

***Update to add the model file for Product and the error for removing the <%= product.\ %> lines per comments below.***

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :\, :description, :image_url, :price, :title
end


NoMethodError in Products#index

Showing C:/Sites/work/depot/app/views/products/index.html.erb where line #15 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #15):

12:     <th></th>
13:   </tr>
14: 
15: <% @products.each do |product| %>
16:   <tr>
17:     
18:     <td><%= product.title %></td>
Rails.root: C:/Sites/work/depot
```

**Further edited to add Controller file**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/new
  # GET /products/new.json
  def new
    @product = Product.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /products/1
  # PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You sure the example contains `product.\ `? I've never seen this being used. If it's not that important, just remove this line. and the corresponding `<th>\</th>`

Comment: Thanks for your very quick response. They didn't show the code in the book - this was the code that was automatically created using the generate scaffold command for Product.  I did try removing the line and it gave a "NoMethodError" instead of a SyntaxError.  Edit to add:  the NoMethodError referred to line 15 when the product.\ and <th> were removed.

Comment: can you show the model file for `Product` and the error after you removed those two lines?

Comment: sure thing - please see edited OP

Comment: Can you put up the controller file as well. It's saying that `.each` is used on a nil class which is addressing `@products`. Since you aren't using the `.\ ` in the index file. You might as well remove `:\ ` from the model file in `attr_accessible :\, :description, :image_url, :price, :title`

Comment: Thanks.  Added the controller file.

Comment: Also, could you tell me what it is that the .\ is supposed to do?  It's impossible to google that punctuation sequence and the book doesn't mention it.

Comment: The controller file looks fine. I have no idea what `.\ ` does. I suspect that when you type in the scaffold command and accidentally put in `\ ` since scaffold won't create an attribute on its own. You might as well destroy this scaffold and redo it to make sure `\ ` don't mess up other things. Or you can alter the table and drop the `\ ` column in your `products` table.

Comment: Aha!  I think you're right.  This is the command sample from the book, so I think I may have taken the slash too literally as it may just have been meant as a line break or something.  depot> rails generate scaffold Product \ title:string description:text image_url:string price:decimal

Comment: Yep, that worked.  Thanks a bunch - I may have been trapped on that for a while. Feel like an idiot.

Comment: it's all good. You gonna run into lots more errors from now on, happy railing.

Comment: @Chris That `\ ` backslash is used to escape a linebreak. I'm sure that scaffold was written on two lines in the book.

Answer (score 0):

modify `@products.each` to `@product.each`. And delete line of "\".